# How to match and merge the pandas Dataframe with the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I have a simple pandas data frame and list which is as fallows

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

mylist =['cat blue', 'sky green', 'dog black']
```

how to find the match between this dataframe and list. I got the result when the list is like

```
mylist_1 = ['cat','sky','dog']
```

But when i try to solve with **mylist** the dataframe is not matching. Here is the piece of code which i used.

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

print(frame)

mylist_1 =['cat', 'sky', 'dog']

import nltk
frame['Data'] = frame['a'].apply(lambda x :  ([i for i in nltk.word_tokenize(x) if i in mylist_1]))

print(frame)
```

But how to match with the **my_list** with the dataframe. Please help me on this issue

Comment: `But when i try to solve with mylist the dataframe is not matching.`: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50317114/edit) to show us *precisely* what you see? And also what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you don't need to use `nltk.word_tokenize`, you can just use `split(' ')` in a list comprehension, using the same structure as you were trying to use:

```
frame['data'] = (frame.a.apply(lambda x: [w for i in mylist
                                          for w in i.split(' ')
                                          if w in (x)]))
>>> frame
                  a          data
0   the cat is blue   [cat, blue]
1  the sky is green  [sky, green]
2  the dog is black  [dog, black]
```

The list comprehension: `[w for i in mylist for w in i.split(' ')]` flattens your list to `['cat', 'blue', 'sky', 'green', 'dog', 'black']`